# How can the Network Administrator check the Transfer files History between remote PCs?

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking, wireless-networking

I wonder how could the network administrator check the history of the transferred files between different users or remote PCs, and in case if someone transferred data from a network PC to his external usb hard drive is there anyway to know the data that he copied or transferred?

Regards,

Comment: Impossible to answer, as it depends on what type of logging the system administrator has enabled. But if you are trying to hide something from your system administrator always assume they can see all you do. (source: I'm a sysadmin)

Answer (score 2):

There is no native capability for this.

That is why many organisations ban the use of USB drives.

Personally, I believe this to be counter-productive in most situations. That is because there is simply **no** way to prevent data-loss from an organisation that uses Internet connected computing facilities. There are too many ways to transfer data.

To get a better answer than this, we would need to understand more about the reasons you wanted to prevent the transfer of data, the people and risk involved. Such security measures are not trivial, come with a significant cost and affect the day-to-day running of the organisation.

Better to hire trusted people, treat them (and pay them) well, write (and enforce) good acceptable use policies and restrict access to sensitive data.